# Difference between "public void onDestroy()" and "protected void onDestroy()"?

Tags: android, private, void, protected, code-cleanup

Here is a part of my code:

```
package com.admobsdk_dfp_handler;

import com.google.ads.*;
import com.google.ads.doubleclick.*;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class AdMobSDK_DFP_Handler extends Activity {
    private DfpAdView adView;
    private static final String adUnitId = "/7732/test_portal7/android_app1_test_portal7/top_banner_non_sdk_application_android_app1_test_portal7";
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
            handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ad_mob_sdk__dfp__handler);

        adView = new DfpAdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, adUnitId);

        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

        layout.addView(adView);

        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());

    };

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000);
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_ad_mob_sdk__dfp__handler,
                menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**protected** void onDestroy() is used to clean up the program. However, I saw some sample projects, which usually use **public** void onDestroy() to do the clean up.

As I know that in Java, **protected** method can be accessed within a package, and **public** method can be accessed anywhere. But usually a class has its own onDestroy(), so is it mean that either one can be used?? Any points I have to concern about while choosing between them?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Between public and protected there's no difference in the functionality. The only difference is that with public you will be able to call `onDestroy()` on an instance of the activity from any class. With protected you can call only in the same class or subclasses in the same package. With `onDestroy()` I don't see a lot of sense in making it public. It could be actually bad practice.

In other words, just use protected unless you have a very special reason to make it accessible to more classes.

I think the public implementations you saw is just a mistake / not necessary. If you want to test just change it back to protected. If there are no compiler errors, it's not necessary.

Comment: Sorry there's some mistakes in my question, it is public instead of private

Answer (score 2):

The definition of `onDestroy` in Activity is `protected onDestroy()`. In your subclass of Activity, you can write `protected onDestroy` or `public onDestroy` and the compiler will not complain. The more conventionally accepted programming practice would be to write `protected onDestroy`, minimising the exposure of the method. However, Writing `public onDestroy` is highly unlikely ever to cause a bug. So people put it in without thinking and forget about it. At least, that's what I do.

Answer (score 0):

onDestroy() is one of the lifecycle methods of activity. To create your own activity you should extend the activity class.

In android's activity class, all life cycle methods are protected since it recommended by java's best practice to have access restriction to these lifecycle methods only in derived classes.

It won't create any problem even if you use public onDestroy() but as per the recommended best practices, we should keep it protected.

To get clear understanding please check this below link.
https://www.baeldung.com/java-protected-access-modifier